# Get parameter values from DBCC INPUTBUFFER

Tags: sql-server

I've created a trigger on a SQL Server 2012 table to log all INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE actions against the table to another table.  I got my initial code from the blog post at http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2010/01/11/tsql2sday-using-sys-dm-exec-sql-text-to-get-the-calling-statement.aspx.

Here are the scripts for a test table, the table I'm logging changes on the test table to, and the trigger on the test table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestAddresses](
    [RecNo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Address] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [State] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [Zip] [varchar](12) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
-------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestAddressesLog](
    [RecNo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Sql] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestAddressesLog] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TestAddressesLog_Sql]  DEFAULT (N'') FOR [Sql]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestAddressesLog] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TestAddressesLog_Timestamp]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Timestamp]
GO
------------------------------------
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TestAddressLogTrigger]
   ON  [dbo].[TestAddresses]
   FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
AS 
BEGIN 

   DECLARE @TEMP TABLE  (EventType NVARCHAR(30), Parameters INT, EventInfo NVARCHAR(4000)) 
   INSERT INTO @TEMP EXEC('DBCC INPUTBUFFER(@@SPID)') 

   INSERT INTO TestAddressesLog (Sql) 
        SELECT EventInfo FROM @TEMP 
END
```

This works great for standard CRUD operations where there are no parameters.  However, when my .NET code executes a parameterized operation such as the following (assigning a value such as 'CA' to @NewState):

```
UPDATE TestAddresses SET State = @NewState WHERE State = 'TX'
```

I get the following result:

```
(@NewState int)UPDATE TestAddresses SET State = @NewState WHERE State = 'TX'
```

I need a way to get and record the value of the passed parameter.  Anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

That's not going to work. The only way is to capture RPC Completed events using Extended Events, parse them and persist them.